# Optimize controls animation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There are code in the project that implements simple "animation" - slide. There is pictureBox as content unit, and two buttons to slide to next pictureBox, or to previous. This code uses winforms.

To implement this "slide", location for both pictureboxes changes in cycle. But the control that slides to the screen (its start location out of the screen), does not redraw properly. So we tried to add refresh of content panel to the cycle (like *this.contentPanel.Refresh()*). And it worked fine. But problems occured when QAs tested this application on very slow VM. This animation took ages, because of that refsresh in cycle.

As quickfix we refactored code to perform this animation for constant time. So slow machine can animatie it for same time, but not so smoothly.

**The question is, how can we optimize this? How can we redraw this controls more optimal?**

Comment: There's no indication whatsoever that you are not already drawing at the maximum achievable rate.  Consider adding the "we've got a very slow VM" option that turns the animation off.

Comment: The probem is that only redraw causes this performance gaps. If i slide control that currently on screen (so its already drawed and does not need redraw), than even this slow VM does it fine. I hope there is the way for example, to draw second control once (that out of screen) so it will not need redrawing.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to make this faster (and for sure it's not possible to make it 'more optimal' :). However, you can write a custom control which will load 2 images and paint them appropriately